# Android Native Push Notification using Mobile First

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Can any one explain how the mobile first server push notifications are managed?

Currently what i understand from android perspective, google(GCM) queues the notification messages sent from backend system and send it to registered clients.

How does mobile first server implement it ? Would it talk to GCM ?

I couldn't find any nice explanation related to it on how mobile first server interacts with google.

Comment: This question is not a good fit for SO.

Comment: what does this mean?

Comment: Stack Overflow is meant for programming questions.

Comment: I am running into the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MobileFirst Platform does not implement its own push notifications service. Rather it provides you with an API through which you can then send notifications via the various push notification services (APNS, MPNS and GCM).

In the context of a Hybrid application (which is written in web  technologies), you can target your application to iOS, Android and Windows/Phone 8 and use the same single API in JavaScript to get push setup and work across all of those environments, instead of writing specifically for each environment using its own programming language of choice (Objective-C/Swift, C#, Java).

That's what MFP gives you in the context of push notification (in addition to different implementation types with added security and other features). MFP has the underlying infrastructure to talk with this different vendors, doing the "dirty work" for you.

In the MFP Developer Center: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/notifications/push-notifications-hybrid-applications/

In the IBM user documentation: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/admin/c_push_notification.html?lang=en - also contains pretty diagrams